# Basics question about the empirical rule

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Have a very basic question regarding the empirical rule. Does it mean that when I take a sample of 30 items and calculate the mean, 95% of the distribution lies between mean +/- 2 sigma? Does the sigma here mean the sample standard deviation or population standard deviation? Also, if I am viewing it as a Unimodal distribution, can I state that 95% of the population lies below mean + 3 sigma? How does tolerance intervals align with empirical rule?

I am self learning. Please bear with me. Thanks a lot in advent.

Comment: When you said "95% of the distribution lies between mean +/- 2 sigma", did you mean the sample mean and the true distribution? Then the answer is NO. About 95% of the underlying distribution lies in the $3\sigma$ band of $\mu$, where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are population mean and standard deviation.

Comment: @yarna It's difficult to see how you can assert one of those statements and not the other--especially when neither is generally true.  The "empirical rule" is a simple rule of thumb used for quick assessments of data under minimal assumptions.  See Feedman et al, *Statistics.*  To other people this rule has a much narrower meaning of simply memorizing percentiles of the standard Normal distribution: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule, for example.

Comment: Now I am again confused.

Comment: @whuber I don't quite follow you. I commented the above assuming univariate normal distribution, and for that it is always true.

Comment: Check the example in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality. Is that a correct use? “But if we additionally know that the distribution is normal, we can say there is a 75% chance the word count is between 770 and 1230 (which is an even tighter bound).” This sounds like a tolerance interval like statement.

Comment: @yarna Under that limited assumption, your first statement is correct for small samples but not for large and your second statement is never correct (perhaps you accidentally wrote "$3\sigma$" instead of "$2\sigma$"?).

Comment: That's it. Sorry. Yes, I meant $2\sigma$. For $3\sigma$, it will be approximately 99.73%.

Comment: ER is "precisely" true for normal pop: ` diff(pnorm(c(-1,1)))` returns 0.6826895;
`diff(pnorm(c(-2,2)))` 0.9544997; `diff(pnorm(c(-3,3)))`
0.9973002. Roughly true for normal samples, but many textbook examples are contrived to give atypically close results. 1-sigma part surprisingly good for exponential pop.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment** continued:  Among standard normal samples of size $n=100.$ the Empirical Rule would imply $\approx 84\%$ below $1,$ but the variation is high.

```
pr = replicate(10^6, mean(rnorm(100) < 1))
hist(pr, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
abline(v=.84, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: @ BruceET. Thank you. What I am taking from all the answers is that the empirical rule is applicable only for the sample collected. Thus, if you have a sample of 100, the ER is applicable for the 100 samples. If you have all the data for population, then the ER holds. But, we cannot use ER from the data of a sample and apply to the population. Is this right?

Comment: Textbooks often apply the ER to a 'mound shaped' sample. Many such samples have about 95% of their observations within the interval $\bar X \pm 2S.$ That helps elem students gain intuition about std deviation, also sets the stage for the idea of confidence intervals. More often useful for rough intuition than for accurate estimates, // The related "$6\sigma$ rule" that nearly all obs are within a span of 6 std devs is often misleading. The "rule" to estimate $S$ as $1/6$th of sample range is of some use if $n$ is a few dozen; misleading for tiny or huge samples.